# QT open file with Shared access

Tags: qt, file, io

I am looking for a cross-platform way of opening file in a way that other applications can   read and write into it. The Windows's API has this functionality:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y973b725(v=vs.110).aspx
( FileShare parameter )

Is there any way this to be done with QT in a cross-platform fashion.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App is cross-platform or you need access cross-platform machines?

### If "app cross-platform" you can try:

Unfortunately I found no "source" that is "cross-platform" for this task, I can refer you to is a way to access windows machines (or supporting samba).

```
#include <QMessageBox>

...

QString file;

#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    //app compiled in Linux (requires samba)
    file = "smb://PC/folder/file.txt";
#endif
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN32
    //app compiled in Windows (x86)
    file = "\\\\PC\\folder\\file.txt"; // "\\PC\FOLDER\filer.txt"
#endif

QFile test(file);
if (test.exists()){
    QMessageBox::about(NULL, "1", "exists");
} else {
    QMessageBox::about(NULL, "1", "not exists");
}
```

defines for differents platforms:

```
Q_OS_DARWIN64
Q_OS_DARWIN32
Q_OS_ANDROID
Q_OS_LINUX
Q_OS_CYGWIN
Q_OS_WIN32
Q_OS_WIN64
Q_OS_WINCE
Q_OS_WINPHONE
Q_OS_WINRT
Q_OS_SOLARIS
Q_OS_HPUX
Q_OS_ULTRIX
Q_OS_RELIANT
Q_OS_NACL
Q_OS_FREEBSD
Q_OS_FREEBSD_KERNEL
Q_OS_BSD4
Q_OS_NETBSD
Q_OS_OPENBSD
Q_OS_BSDI
Q_OS_IRIX
Q_OS_OSF
Q_OS_AIX
Q_OS_LYNX
Q_OS_HURD
Q_OS_DGUX
Q_OS_QNX
Q_OS_DYNIX
Q_OS_SCO
Q_OS_UNIXWARE
Q_OS_INTEGRITYQ_OS_VXWORKS
```

### If you want to access different machines:

I can let you know is that you will have to detect open "ports" on the machine (test it), access is by the "ports".